# How to solve multiple processes writing to the same file using keras' fit generator's multiprocessing mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, io, multiprocessing

So basically I wrote a keras generator to download images from a web server while it trains. This was an attempt to speed up training so that the training didn't have to wait for the entire batch of images to download before the training began.

To really speed this up I'd like to enable multiprocessing on the keras fit_generator function. However, sometimes keras attempts to download the same image multiple times at once. Not only is this inefficient, it also crashes the program as multiple processes attempt to write to the same file at once. This problem doesn't happen when multiprocessing is False, even with multiple workers. I assume this is due to the GIL.

Normally you could use locks to ensure that the same file is only written to once. However, I don't see how to do this using keras. If anyone could give me some pointers that'd be great. Thanks for reading.

Here's the code that crashes:

```
 image_name = str(image['image'])
 try:
     obj = self.client.get_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Key=SRC_IMG_FOLDER + image_name)
     obj_image = Image.open(obj['Body'])

     if self.image_extension not in image_name:
         image_name += self.image_extension
     obj_image.save(self.image_path(image_index))
```

The saving of the file is where I run into issues.

Comment: How about downloading on first epoch and later reusing them ? In that case, you just need to check if the files exists or not, based on the file name. This is a simplest of solutions i could think of.

Comment: The problem with that is that even on the first epoch keras can reuse the same image. In fact, the default behavior is that I have no control over which images are chosen to be downloaded by keras. I thought about checking if the image is already downloaded before proceeding, and I implemented it and it appears to mostly fix the problem. However, it's still possible that another process starts downloading an image after the check is preformed, as if statements aren't atomic. Not to mention that checking the entire folder for existing images every time an image is selected is expensive.

Comment: What you mentioned is right. But if we run more epochs, the image might get downloaded again and again right ? if we don't perform any check ?

Comment: is it possible for you share the part of code where you do the multi threading inside the custom data_generator you created ?

Comment: As far as I know epochs don't really matter here, keras just uses and reuses whatever images it wants, whenever it wants. As far as I can tell this means we have to preform the check every single time keras chooses a new image. I'm just not sure how to preform this check atomically. I don't manually do any multithreading. I'm using a keras fit_generator which allows me to pass in multiprocessing=True. This allows keras to start up multiple processes all accessing my generator in parallel. I'll edit my post with the part that's crashing, though.

Comment: how about maintaining a global dictionary in the python code which act as log, which holds the image names as keys and the value is a boolean which gets True when ever the image is downloaded. instead of checking the file system for the availability of the file, you can check this dictionary which will reduce the computation also.

Comment: also please have a look at this discussion - https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1638

Comment: A global dictionary would work, the problem however is that once the processes are spawned they each get their own copy of the dictionary. Any changes by a process are only noticed by that process. There might be a way to do interprocess communication to update this structure, but I don't see how with keras.

Comment: you are right. seems to be an interesting scenario to tackle. i will also look for more solutions.

Comment: Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I think I figured it out if anyone in the future has a similar problem. I simply use `os.open(file_path, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL)` which will atomically open a file. I catch the FileExistsError and wait for the file to finish downloading in that process. This ensures that the same file cannot be downloaded twice.